# Why are extra blank lines generated while writing to file?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find specific lines in a file, add a string to end of that line, and then update the file, but the updated file has extra blank lines between the lines.

```py
def Reading_Logging(PacketName, PacketTot, PacketNum):
    try:

        with open("C:\\Users\\Shakib\\Desktop\\test.txt", "r+") as f:
            content = f.read().splitlines()
            #print(names_list)
            for i, l in enumerate(content):
                tnow = datetime.datetime.now()
                linesplit = l.split(',')
                if linesplit[0] == PacketName and linesplit[1] == PacketTot and linesplit[2] == PacketNum:
                    content[i] = content[i].replace(content[i], content[i] + ',' + str(tnow))
            with open("C:\\Users\\Shakib\\Desktop\\newtest.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write('\n'.join(content))
```

I expect the following output without blank lines, but this is my real output:

```
ZoYt,97,0,3.394531,2019-07-27 14:40:27.671415,2019-07-27 19:22:48.824541

ZoYt,97,1,3.000977,2019-07-27 14:40:27.701415

ZoYt,97,2,1.879883,2019-07-27 14:40:27.731415

ZoYt,97,3,3.681641,2019-07-27 14:40:27.753415

ZoYt,97,4,1.069336,2019-07-27 14:40:27.760416

ZoYt,97,5,1.094727,2019-07-27 14:40:27.773417

ZoYt,97,6,3.077148,2019-07-27 14:40:27.787417

ZoYt,97,7,1.015625,2019-07-27 14:40:27.798418

ZoYt,97,8,3.765625,2019-07-27 14:40:27.813419

ZoYt,97,9,2.797852,2019-07-27 14:40:27.823419

ZoYt,97,10,3.860352,2019-07-27 14:40:27.837420

ZoYt,97,11,3.179688,2019-07-27 14:40:27.849421
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `'\n'.join(content)`... try removing the `\n`.

Comment: removing \n makes makes all the lines in one single line without any line feed

Comment: Take out the `join` or try putting two lines above `... str(tnow) + '\n')